# Why AWS allows ListObjects in one server and denied on another server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the python code that fetch all the files from AWS S3. But the problem is the code runs on one server but error occurs on another. I tried to run on docker container too . But the same error occurs.

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

My python code is:

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    ug = s3.Bucket("bucket")
    file_path = []
    ug_objects = ug.objects.filter(
                Prefix='prefix')
    for obj in ug_objects:     //error occurs at this line
```

I guess it is not the permission issue because it is running on another server

Comment: Did you configure .aws folder or supply the API access key?

Comment: I build the docker image and supplied all the credentials from the environment file.

Comment: Like this ? https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/

Comment: Created a .env files as

`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=MY-SECRET-KEY
`
AND run the docker command as

`docker run -it -d --name  name --env-file .env  conrtainer_name
`

Comment: I will suggest you first try out the credential directly from the server. If it works, then try the way of the mentioned docker documentation.

Comment: Yes its working directly from the server

Comment: Please try the given documentation example.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked. Do we need to give the  docker image permission for accessing the s3?

Comment: Oh wait, when you say "another server", do you mean server in another VPC or another account? If such case, you need to add the specific account access right into your bucket policies.

Comment: With python36 I'm getting same error while it's working fine with python35